# How do I change the text of a specific table cell based on class name and sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, siblings

I want to use jQuery to rename some text based on class and text within a sibling's tag. For example I'm trying to rename `Sally` to `Samantha` in the HTML below, based on the text within the sibling `.field1` `td` (which is `421`).

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="adv-grid-row">
            <td class="adv-grid-cell description">Sally</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell units">Jibber</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell field8">Jabber</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell field1">421</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell part_number">433</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell field25">John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="adv-grid-row">
            <td class="adv-grid-cell description">Test</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell units">Each</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell field8">Part</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell field1">450</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell part_number">431</td>
            <td class="adv-grid-cell field25">Joe</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
$(".adv-grid-cell.field1 td:contains('421')").siblings(".adv-grid-cell.description").text('Samantha');
```

If that's not possible, how do I just look for "Sally" using the td's class and rename it to "Samantha"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect; the `.field1` *is* the `td` which contains the text. Try this:

```
$(".adv-grid-cell.field1:contains('421')").siblings(".adv-grid-cell.description").text('Samantha');
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dguyvtna/)

It's worth noting that the `:contains` selector matches on the provided string being anywhere in the `innerText` of the DOMElement, so it would match `421`, `a421z` and `not 421`. If you need to match on `421` *only*, you would need to use `filter()`:

```
$('.adv-grid-cell.field1').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == '421';
}).siblings(".adv-grid-cell.description").text('Samantha');
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I grabbed an extension called 'containsExact' and matched the exact '421'.

Comment: Glad to help. Downloading an extra script seems a little overkill, as the `filter()` is just an extra line. I updated my answer to show you the code for it.